# Show hide password

Tags: javascript, html, loopingselector

I'm currently learning javascript. It works when I have one input, but when I have more than one I'm confused about looping through the icon and the input. What do you think is the problem?. Sorry for my bad english. I hope you understand what i talking about

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.show-hide-password');
const icon = document.querySelectorAll('i.password');

// Experiment 1
icon.forEach(function (ele) {
   ele.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      const targetInput = e.target.previousElementSibling.getAttribute('type');
      if (targetInput == 'password') {
          targetInput.type = 'text';
          ele.classList.remove('fa-eye-slash');
          ele.classList.add('fa-eye');
      } else if (targetInput == 'text') {
          targetInput.type = 'password';
          ele.classList.add('fa-eye-slash');
          ele.classList.remove('fa-eye');
      }
   });
});

// Experiment 2
// icon.forEach(function (ele) {
//   ele.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
//      inputs.forEach(function (input) {
//         const targetInput = input.getAttribute('type');
//         if (targetInput == 'password') {
//             targetInput.type = 'text';
//             ele.classList.remove('fa-eye-slash');
//             ele.classList.add('fa-eye');
//          } else if (targetInput == 'text') {
//             targetInput.type = 'password';
//             ele.classList.add('fa-eye-slash');
//             ele.classList.remove('fa-eye');
//          }
//      });
//   });
//});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">

<div class="form-group">
   <label>New Password</label>
   <input type="password" class="form-control show-hide-password" autocomplete="off" required>
   <i class="fa fa-eye-slash password"></i>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Confirm New Password</label>
   <input type="password" class="form-control show-hide-password" autocomplete="off" required>
   <i class="fa fa-eye-slash password"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change the element attribute with [`Element.setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) like this:

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.show-hide-password');
const icon = document.querySelectorAll('i.password');

// Experiment 1
icon.forEach(function (ele) {
   ele.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      const targetInput = e.target.previousElementSibling.getAttribute('type');
      if (targetInput == 'password') {
          e.target.previousElementSibling.setAttribute('type', 'text');
          ele.classList.remove('fa-eye-slash');
          ele.classList.add('fa-eye');
      } else if (targetInput == 'text') {
          e.target.previousElementSibling.setAttribute('type', 'password');
          ele.classList.add('fa-eye-slash');
          ele.classList.remove('fa-eye');
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">

<div class="form-group">
   <label>New Password</label>
   <input type="password" class="form-control show-hide-password" autocomplete="off" required>
   <i class="fa fa-eye-slash password"></i>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Confirm New Password</label>
   <input type="password" class="form-control show-hide-password" autocomplete="off" required>
   <i class="fa fa-eye-slash password"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: whats different beetwen `e.target.previousElementSibling.setAttribute('type', 'text');` and `targetInput.type = 'text';` ? @GuerricP

Comment: Once you've extracted an attribute with `getAttribute` it's not linked to the element anymore so you need `setAttribute` otherwise the new value is set to the `targetInput` object only, and it has no effect

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the explanation, and for your time too